# Error : unresolved external

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, linker, borland-c++

```
S:\builds\g2.0\upr\g\platform\client\errlib>make
MAKE Version 5.0  Copyright (c) 1987, 1997 Borland International
        tlink32 /v /ap /aa /Tpd /OS /LE:\BC5\LIB @MAKE0000.@@@
Turbo Link  Version 2.0.68.0 Copyright (c) 1993,1997 Borland International
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'WEP'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'ERRSETDLG'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'ERR_LOG'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'ERR_LOG_INT'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'HDLR_ERR_DISPLAY'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'ISDONE'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'RPC_RETMSG'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'RPC_M_ON'
Warning: Attempt to export non-public symbol 'RPC_M_OFF'
Warning: .DEF file heap reserve size < 64K; 1MB default will be used
Error: Unresolved external 'B_GetUserDir' referenced from module err_log.c
Error: Unresolved external 'B_getstudyname' referenced from module err_log.c
Error: Unresolved external 'B_getcustname' referenced from module err_log.c
```

these are the linking errors i am getting while compiling second module i.e. (Errlib) which is dependent on first modules lib file i.e. (barlib.lib). first module already compiled and it generated dll and .lib file.

First module make file (barlib)

```
#
# This makefile builds the BARLIB dll:
#         barlib.dll
# and a stub version:
#         sbarlib.dll
# and the associated import library:
#         barlib.lib
#
# The stub version must be renamed in order to "use" it.
#
# The following macros must be set to run this makefile:
#    PLATF_LIB       Platform library directory (i.e. c:\p3.0\client\lib)
#    PLATF_INC       Platform header directory (i.e. c:\p3.0\client\hdr)
#    PLATF_DLL       Platform DLL directory (i.e. c:\p3.0\client\dll)
#    BORLAND_LIB     Borland compiler library directory (i.e. c:\bc4\lib)
#    BORLAND_INC     Borland compiler header directory (i.e. c:\bc4\include)
#
.autodepend
# Set DEBUG to 0 (production) or 1 (development) (may be overridden
# by environment variable on build PC).
DEBUG = 1

# Common macros
NAME        =barlib
#MEMMODEL    =l
OBJS        =alltbls.obj \
             breaddir.obj \
             custudy.obj \
             getlist.obj \
             getname.obj \
             rdtbl.obj \
             rdwrdesc.obj \
             tableio.obj \
             userdir.obj
COMLIBS     =
RCFILES     =

# Application specific macros
COMBIN      =$(PLATF_DLL)
COMLIB      =$(PLATF_LIB)
COMINC      =-I$(PLATF_INC);$(BORLAND_INC)
RCINC       =-I$(PLATF_INC);$(BORLAND_INC)
LIBPATH     =$(BORLAND_LIB)
#WINLIBS     =import crtldll
WINLIBS     =import32 cw32i
LIBS        =$(COMLIBS) $(TARGETLIBS) $(WINLIBS)

# Main (default) target
goal:       $(COMBIN)\$(NAME).dll $(COMBIN)\s$(NAME).dll $(COMLIB)\$(NAME).lib

# Build options macros
!if $(DEBUG)
# Debugging options
#COMLOPT     =/v /l /m /Twd /L$(LIBPATH)
COMLOPT     =-v -aa -Tpd -L$(LIBPATH)

CLOPT       =-y -v -O-
!else
# No Debugging options
COMLOPT     =/x /Twd /L$(LIBPATH)
CLOPT       =@opt.cfg
!endif

CPU         =-3
WARN        =-w
#MEMMOD      =-m$(MEMMODEL)!
MEMMOD      =-l$(MEMMODEL)!
#CFLAGS      =bcc32 -c -P-.C -WDE -D_RTLDLL $(COMINC) $(CPU) $(MEMMOD) $(CLOPT) $(WARN)
CFLAGS      =bcc32 -c -P-.C -WDR -D_RTLDLL $(COMINC) $(CPU) $(CLOPT) $(WARN)
LINK        =ilink32 $(COMLOPT)
RC          =brc32

#  Standard inference rules
.c.obj:
    $(CFLAGS) $*.c

.rc.res:
    $(RC) $(RCINC) -r $*.rc

$(COMBIN)\$(NAME).dll: $(OBJS) $(NAME).def $(COMLIBS)
    $(LINK) @&&|
    c0d32 $(OBJS),        \ 
    $@,     \
    $(NAME).map,    \
    $(COMLIBS) $(WINLIBS),  \
    $(NAME).def
|

$(COMBIN)\s$(NAME).dll: sbarlib.obj $(NAME).def
    $(LINK) @&&|
    c0d32 sbarlib.obj,        \ 
    $@,     \
    s$(NAME).map,    \
    $(WINLIBS),  \
    $(NAME).def
|

$(COMLIB)\$(NAME).lib: $(NAME).def
    implib $@ $?

alltbls.c: ..\..\common\barlib\alltbls.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

breaddir.c: ..\..\common\barlib\breaddir.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

custudy.c: ..\..\common\barlib\custudy.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

getlist.c: ..\..\common\barlib\getlist.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

getname.c: ..\..\common\barlib\getname.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

rdtbl.c: ..\..\common\barlib\rdtbl.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

rdwrdesc.c: ..\..\common\barlib\rdwrdesc.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

tableio.c: ..\..\common\barlib\tableio.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

userdir.c: ..\..\common\barlib\userdir.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

clean:
    -del *.obj
    -del *.map
```

second module make file (errlib)

```
#
# This makefile builds the ERRLIB dll:
#         errlib.dll
# and a stub version:
#         serrlib.dll
# and the associated import library:
#         errlib.lib
#
# The stub version must be renamed in order to "use" it.
#
# The following macros must be set to run this makefile:
#    PLATF_LIB       Platform library directory (i.e. c:\p3.0\client\lib)
#    PLATF_INC       Platform header directory (i.e. c:\p3.0\client\hdr)
#    PLATF_DLL       Platform DLL directory (i.e. c:\p3.0\client\dll)
#    BORLAND_LIB     Borland compiler library directory (i.e. c:\bc4\lib)
#    BORLAND_INC     Borland compiler header directory (i.e. c:\bc4\include)
#
.autodepend
# Set DEBUG to 0 (production) or 1 (development) (may be overridden
# by environment variable on build PC).
DEBUG = 1

# Common macros
NAME        =errlib
#MEMMODEL    =32
OBJS        =err_log.obj \
             errhdisp.obj \
             gwrnflag.obj \
             isdone.obj \
             rcretmsg.obj
COMLIBS     = $(PLATF_LIB)\barlib.lib
RCFILES     =

# Application specific macros
COMBIN      =$(PLATF_DLL)
COMLIB      =$(PLATF_LIB)
COMINC      =-I$(PLATF_INC);$(BORLAND_INC)
RCINC       =-I$(PLATF_INC);$(BORLAND_INC)
LIBPATH     =$(BORLAND_LIB)
#WINLIBS     =import crtldll
WINLIBS     =import32 cw32i
LIBS        =$(COMLIBS) $(TARGETLIBS) $(WINLIBS)
#BARLIBPATH  =S:\builds\g2.0\upr\g\platform\client\barlib

# Main (default) target
goal:       $(COMBIN)\$(NAME).dll $(COMBIN)\s$(NAME).dll $(COMLIB)\$(NAME).lib

# Build options macros
!if $(DEBUG)
# Debugging options
#COMLOPT     =/v /l /m /Twd /L$(LIBPATH)
COMLOPT     =/v /ap /aa /Tpd /OS /L$(LIBPATH)  
CLOPT       =-y -v -O-
!else
# No Debugging options
COMLOPT     =/v /ap /aa /Tpd /OS/ /L$(LIBPATH) 
CLOPT       =@opt.cfg
!endif

CPU         =-3
WARN        =-w
MEMMOD      =-l$(MEMMODEL)!
#CFLAGS      =bcc -c -P-.C -WDE -D_RTLDLL $(COMINC) $(CPU) $(MEMMOD) $(CLOPT) $(WARN)
CFLAGS      =bcc32 -c -P-.C -WDE -D_RTLDLL $(COMINC) $(CPU) $(CLOPT) $(WARN)
LINK        =tlink32 $(COMLOPT)
RC          =brc32

#  Standard inference rules
.c.obj:
    $(CFLAGS) $*.c

.rc.res:
    $(RC) $(RCINC) -r $*.rc

$(COMBIN)\$(NAME).dll: $(OBJS) $(NAME).def $(COMLIBS)
    $(LINK) @&&|
    c0d32 $(OBJS),        \ 
    $@,     \
    $(NAME).map,    \
    $(COMLIBS) $(WINLIBS),  \
    $(NAME).def
|

$(COMBIN)\s$(NAME).dll: serrlib.obj $(NAME).def
    $(LINK) @&&|
    c0d32 serrlib.obj,        \ 
    $@,     \
    s$(NAME).map,    \
    $(WINLIBS),  \
    $(NAME).def
|

$(COMLIB)\$(NAME).lib: $(NAME).def
    implib $@ $?

err_log.c: ..\..\common\errlib\err_log.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

errhdisp.c: ..\..\common\errlib\errhdisp.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

gwrnflag.c: ..\..\common\errlib\gwrnflag.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

isdone.c: ..\..\common\errlib\isdone.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@

#msg_hand.c: ..\..\common\errlib\msg_hand.c
#   if exist $@ del $@
#   unix2dos $? $@

#serrlib.c: ..\..\common\errlib\serrlib.c
#   if exist $@ del $@
#   unix2dos $? $@

rcretmsg.c: ..\..\common\errlib\rcretmsg.c
    if exist $@ del $@
    unix2dos $? $@


clean:
    -del *.obj
    -del *.map
```

Definition file of barlib

```
LIBRARY BARLIB
CODE PRELOAD MOVEABLE DISCARDABLE
DATA PRELOAD MOVEABLE SINGLE
HEAPSIZE 50000
EXPORTS
    B_INIT_TABLES                  @2   
    B_ADDSTUDY                     @3   
    B_SELSTUDY                     @4   
    B_SVSTUDY                      @5   
    B_RMSTUDY                      @6   
    B_RMWKSTUDY                    @7   
    B_CKCHANGE                     @8   
    B_DISOWNWKSTUDY                @9   
    B_RMCUSTOMER                   @10  
    B_MVCUSTOMER                   @11  
    B_GETCUSTLIST                  @12  
    B_GETSTUDYLIST                 @13  
    B_GETCUSTNAME                  @14  
    B_GETSTUDYNAME                 @15  
    B_RDTBLARRAY                   @16  
    B_RDCUSTDESC                   @17  
    B_WRCUSTDESC                   @18  
    B_RDSTUDYDESC                  @19  
    B_WRSTUDYDESC                  @20  
    B_SETWKSTUDY                   @21  
    B_TBL_OPEN                     @22  
    B_TBL_READ                     @23  
    B_TBL_WRITE                    @24  
    B_TBL_DELETE                   @25  
    B_TBL_UPDATE                   @26  
    _B_TBL_DOCHG                   @27  
    _B_TBL_UNDOCHG                 @28  
    B_TBL_TERMCHG                  @29  
    B_TBL_CLOSE                    @30  
    B_TBL_STATUS                   @31  
    B_GETUSERDIR                   @32  
    B_SETUSERDIR                   @33
```

Please help in resolving these linking error.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you narrow it down a little from the 200+ lines

Comment: I think the module definitions files (errlib.def and barlib.def) are probably quite important to solving this. Also a bit of background can help, is this the first time you've tried to build this, did it suddenly start going wrong, what was the last thing you changed, did you write the code yourself etc. etc.

Comment: please tell me what do you want exactly

Comment: actually this is very old code written in 16bit, now we are making it to work in win7 64 bit. so trying to compile for 32 bit. This is compiled very long back like 10 years before.

Comment: @asgar Cut down your program. A much smaller version that still has the same errors. Trouble is you might not have the skills to achieve this. Hard to tell.

Comment: Make sure you are linking the objs containing the B_getstudyname and B_getcustname

Comment: @asgar My advice would be to port the code to modern compiler.

Comment: @vii barlib.lib file is created and i think errlib module should use this barlib.lib for these functions.

Comment: @john lot of code is there i am just in initial stage. so porting this code to new compiler leads to lot of code changes. now itself we are having code changes since we are trying to compile for 32 bit. (existing is 16 bit)

Comment: @asgar I would expect that you are in for a great many code changes anyway. Seems to me like a good oppotunity to update the code. But you can see the code and I can't so I'm only guessing. Still think the module definition files are important, why not post those?

Comment: @john i have added the definition file of barlib